# Mpu6050 Connection failed

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

I am  using mpu6050 for my project but it shows following error -
Testing device connections...
MPU6050 connection failed
this error is showed only when iI am trying  to use object of MPU6050
but when I don't use instance of MPU6050  and use Wire library instead (like follow) it works -

```
Wire.begin();                      // Initialize communication
Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);       // Start communication with MPU6050 // MPU=0x68
Wire.write(0x6B);                  // Talk to the register 6B
Wire.write(0x00);                  // Make reset - place a 0 into the 6B register
Wire.endTransmission(true);        //end the transmission
```

but I want to use this code -

```
 mpu.initialize(); //start MPU
 Serial.println(F("Testing device connections...")); //debugging serial statement
 Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? F("MPU6050 connection successful") : F("MPU6050 connection failed"));
// supply your own gyro offsets here, scaled for min sensitivity
  mpu.setXGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setYGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setZGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setZAccelOffset(1688);
```

please help me

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the device identifier is not `0x34` (in my case it is `0x39`).
In order not to "cheat" I made the following change:
Comment out this line:

```
Serial.println(accelgyro.testConnection() ? "MPU6050 connection successful" : "MPU6050 connection failed");
```

And inserted these lines:

```
Serial.print("DeviceID: ");
Serial.println(accelgyro.getDeviceID());
```

So the program will write the device identifier instead of giving a response that it didn't find device `0x34`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The problem comes from those lines in the MPU6050.cpp file. You can find it in your sketchbook folder.
To do so: Open the Arduino IDE then File > Preferences > Sketchbook location.

```cpp
//I2Cdev device library code is placed under the MIT license
//Copyright (c) 2012 Jeff Rowberg

/** Verify the I2C connection.
 * Make sure the device is connected and responds as expected.
 * @return True if connection is valid, false otherwise
 */
bool MPU6050::testConnection() {
    return getDeviceID() == 0x34;
}
```

This is the getDeviceId function

```cpp
//I2Cdev device library code is placed under the MIT license
//Copyright (c) 2012 Jeff Rowberg

/** Get Device ID.
 * This register is used to verify the identity of the device (0b110100, 0x34).
 * @return Device ID (6 bits only! should be 0x34)
 * @see MPU6050_RA_WHO_AM_I
 * @see MPU6050_WHO_AM_I_BIT
 * @see MPU6050_WHO_AM_I_LENGTH
 */
uint8_t MPU6050::getDeviceID() {
    I2Cdev::readBits(devAddr, MPU6050_RA_WHO_AM_I, MPU6050_WHO_AM_I_BIT, MPU6050_WHO_AM_I_LENGTH, buffer);
    return buffer[0];
}
```

I just modified the testConnection function to return true, and it worked for me.

```cpp
//I2Cdev device library code is placed under the MIT license
//Copyright (c) 2012 Jeff Rowberg

bool MPU6050::testConnection() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I did what you said and it worked it is printing values but it was printing values even when it said connection failed. but isn't that cheating like we are just returning true? what if there's no actual connection